# Using Lua 5.1, why does finding a point in a sector of a circle fail with big numbers?

Tags: lua, geometry, point

I am using the following function to test if a point is in the given sector of a circle.

```
function PointInSector(point, center, sector_start, sector_end, radius)
    local function are_clockwise(v1, v2)
        return -v1.x * v2.y + v1.y * v2.x > 0
    end

    local function is_in_radius(rp)
        return rp.x * rp.x + rp.y * rp.y <= radius ^ 2
    end

    local rel_pt = {
        x = point.x - center.x,
        y = point.y - center.y
    }

    return not are_clockwise(sector_start, rel_pt) and
           are_clockwise(sector_end, rel_pt) and
           is_in_radius(rel_pt, radius)
end
```

When I plug in numbers like:

```
pt = {
    x = 2,
    y = -2
}

circle_center = {
    x = 0,
    y = 0
}

sector_start = {
    x = 2,
    y = -6
}

sector_end = {
    x = 7,
    y = 1
}

print(PointInSector(pt, circle_center, sector_start, sector_end, 7))
```

[image]

The function returns

```
true
```

However, when I plug in much bigger numbers like the following:

```
pt = {
    x = -130452.63886479,
    y = -1311.5750542283
}

circle_center = {
    x = -131329.64451362,
    y =-2206.0046563482
}

sector_start = {
    x = -128375.22125458,
    y = -1685.0601233474
}

sector_end = {
    x = -131329.64451362,
    y = 793.9953436518
}

print(PointInSector(pt, circle_center, sector_start, sector_end, 5000))
```

[image: visualization of bigger values]

the function returns

```
false
```

Why does the function return `false` here? `point` is in between `sector start` and `sector end`; and is within radius `5000`, so I'm expecting it to return `true` as well. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the algorithm is right? I feel both sector_start and sector_end should minus center first before cross multiply with rel_pt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `rel_sector_start` instead of `sector_start` (and the same about `sector_end`) because you're using `rel_pt` instead of `point`.
Just subtract the center coordinates the same way as you've done for `point`.

Comment: Ah, you're exactly right! Thanks for pointing it out 